# In RunDeck from the bash script file manual error trigger adds multiple rows under the activities tab

Tags: rundeck

In RunDeck in the bash script I am triggering a Linux error to cause job execution failure

```
CODE=`echo $RESULT | head -n1 | cut -c2`
if [ $CODE != '0' ];
then
    exit 1
fi
```

Strange thing is that I am getting four records(failed) instead of one under the activity tab
[image]
Next I tried to add **sleep 20** right above **exit 1** and it logged one record only. As I see some processes still running in RunDeck after **exit 1** command and it continues adding rows in activities. Any Idea how to wait until everything is finished to add only one row under the activity tab?

**EDIT**

Here is full definition

```
#!/bin/bash

set –e

URL="https://my_url"

MY_COMMAND="command_name"

RAW_DATA="[null,\"${MY_COMMAND}\",{}]"
echo "Raw Data ${RAW_DATA}"

RESULT=$(curl "$URL/${MY_COMMAND}" \
    -H 'Accept: application/json' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -H 'User-Agent: my_user_agent' \
    --data-raw $RAW_DATA)
    
echo $RESULT

CODE=`echo $RESULT | head -n1 | cut -c2`
if [ $CODE != '0' ];
then
    exit 1
fi
```

**EDIT 2 - Added Job Definition(YAML)**

```
- defaultTab: output
  description: JOB_DESCRIPTION
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 125cb755-3eaa-49f8-a8b8-dc1004238a44
  loglevel: INFO
  loglimit: 10MB
  loglimitAction: truncate
  loglimitStatus: failed
  name: JOB_NAME
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  notification:
    onfailure:
      email:
        attachLog: true
        attachLogInFile: true
        recipients: someone@mail.com
  notifyAvgDurationThreshold: null
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: {}
  retry: '3'
  schedule:
    dayofmonth:
      day: '*'
    month: '*'
    time:
      hour: '04'
      minute: '05'
      seconds: '0'
    year: '*'
  scheduleEnabled: true
  schedules: []
  sequence:
    commands:
    - script: "#!/bin/bash\n\n"
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  timeout: 1h
  uuid: 125cb755-3eaa-49f8-a8b8-dc1004238a44
```

Comment: Hi, Could you share the example job definition to take a look?

Comment: @MegaDrive68k I am getting HTTP status_code=200 for both the success and failure scenarios. The only thing I see is that it returns an array as a response=[0, "some text"] for success and response=[1, "error text"] for failure. So I need to check if response[0] != '0' I should trigger job failure

Comment: Thanks, that's the script but I meant, the job definition, you can export it in yaml format, take a look: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/creating-jobs.html#exporting-job-definitions

Comment: @MegaDrive68k I've added job definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your job is configured to retry [3 times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/co3FX.jpg) in case of error (the original failed execution + 3 retries = 4 failed executions), you can change this behavior by editing your job > Go to the "Other" tab > Retry textbox. More info [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/creating-jobs.html#retry).

Comment: Thanks a lot, @MegaDrive68k. It was doing 1 original attempt + 3 retries. Now I got how it's working